# Gmail message is rejected

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to send emails from ASP.net project using "System.Net.Mail.MailMessage". I need to add about **30 contacts** to "To" or "BCC" list.

It works for few recipients but when the number increases;

Gmail give error:

> "**Message rejected**.  See http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=69585 for more information."

And block my accont for sending any more emails for 1 day.

How can i allow gmail to send email to many recipients?
If not what is the alternative way?

Comment: Probably you should use a service that is intended for sending mass mails like [Mailchimp](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/) or [Mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738166-API-Wrappers).

Comment: `See http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=69585 for more information.` is pretty self-explanatory. Also, this is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to comfortably send to 30 addresses.

I tried 40 email addresses for CC list (worked for To list as well) with the following test code,

```
                string mailFrom = "test123@gmail.com";                    
                string mailTo = "testccc@domain.com"; //One of your test emails

                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(mailTo);
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(mailFrom);

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

                mail.Subject = "Test subject";
                mail.Body = "Hello world!!!!";
                //Keep adding your emails as follows, do it in a for loop
                mail.CC.Add("dhanuka1@domain.com");
                mail.CC.Add("dhanuka2@domain.com");
                ...
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mydev@gmail.com", "password");//Your credentials
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
                smtp.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent...");
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, it's a gmail restriction. No code change would solve that.